LinkedIn API Page Statistics - Lifetime Views Decreasing #LinkedIn
I am pulling the Organization Page Statistics data from the LinkedIn API and one of the key metrics returned is all page views {totalPageStatistics_views_allPageViews_pageViews}. The call should be returning lifetime values (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/page-statistics?view=li-lms-2024-04&tabs=http#retrieve-lifetime-organization-page-statistics) but each day when I pull new data, it seems that the value stays relatively stagnant over time and even decreases day to day, which should be impossible if this call were actually pulling lifetime views. My suspicion is that the call is actually filtering to the last 365 days (as seems to be the default within the LinkedIn reporting portal), but the API call indicates it is pulling lifetime data and LinkedIn seems to also indicate that lifetime would be the expected time frame.
I am pulling data through the API built to look at lifetime values, but the page views metrics are decreasing day over day which is impossible for this metric if it were actually looking at a lifetime period.

What is the coding question here? Can you share what you have tried ?

@Mike I've actually submitted this post purely because LinkedIn support requires doing so in order to look into issues with their developer tools

@DM3 could you perhaps add a link to your LinkedIn support ticket?

I was also looking into this, and I think you're right. What I did:

Send a request to https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationPageStatistics to fetch lifetime data, and navigate to the totalPageStatistics.views.allPageViews key.
Send a request to the same endpoint, but this time set timeIntervals.timeRange.start to 365 days ago, and timeIntervals.timeRange.end to today. Now sum all totalPageStatistics.views.allPageViews.pageViews ints.

In my case, the two values are identical (and the organization I'm looking into is older than 1 year).
